# Who or what is the narrator of “Our Talons Can Crush Galaxies”?

Tags: short-stories, character-analysis, brooke-bolander

I just read Brooke Bolander's short story "Our Talons Can Crush Galaxies", which has been nominated for both Hugo and Nebula Awards for Best Short Story after its publication less than a year ago (November 2016) in Uncanny Magazine. It's very short and you can read it in full [here](http://uncannymagazine.com/article/talons-can-crush-galaxies/) (**warning:** contains strong language and potentially disturbing content, about assault and gruesome revenge).

My question is, **exactly what manner of being is the narrator?**

We can tell from the story that she's one of a group of sisters from a millennia-old civilisation, who speak an ancient language, possess great power, and can pass in and out of the "mortal plane". Does the text or subtext suggest a *particular* civilisation and language, a particular kind of mythical creature? Or is it meant to be vague about her exact nature and leave it to our imaginations?

Comment: Thanks to @BESW for [making me aware of this story](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38789793#38789793) by one of his tweet-posts in chat.

Comment: A harpy? (Should that "Who" in the title be a "What"?)

Comment: @user14111 Well, who or what. I don't know if there might be a specific being she's modelled on or just a specific class of being (or neither).